# Trying to add content to an existing dataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've been trying for days to find a solution to my problem. I am trying to add content to a pre-existing column in a data frame, however when I print the screen my program shows me that only the first 100 lines are being modified, it is never shown beyond line 100 and the items are not added but overwritten. I've tried several ways and it always gives an error, the closest way to what I want is this print that I put in the post. Could someone help me, I would be very grateful.

```
import functions
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

pd.set_option('max_rows', 10)
# Module of which the page link returns
site = functions.pagina()

#Browser Options
options = Options()
options.headless = True  # Prevent browser from opening
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)  #Include options in browser

#Run browser with URL
driver.get(site)
# Wait in seconds for the page to load
print('Esperando 5s')
sleep(5)
#Create Data Frame
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['rank','nome','classe','item_lvl','servidor','mortes_temporada'], index=None)



while True:
    #Get the 'next page' variable
    next_page = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#pagination-hook > nav > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a')
    
    #As long as the Next variable is empty
    if next_page is not None:
        #Url of current page
        driver.get(driver.current_url)
        print(driver.current_url[-6:].upper())

        #Attempting to insert data into existing rank column
        ranks = pd.Series([rank_page.text for rank_page in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[4]//div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]')])
        
        #MY PROBLEM ADDING CONTENT TO A COLUMN
        df['rank'] =+ ranks
        

        #Click on Next
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_page)
        sleep(4)
    else:
        break

    print('*' * 80)
    print(df)
    print('*' * 80)
```

[**RETURN PRINT - IMAGE**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMDaF.png)

```
Esperando 5s
PAGE=1
********************************************************************************
   rank nome classe item_lvl servidor mortes_temporada
0     1  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN              NaN
1     2  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN              NaN
2     3  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN              NaN
3     4  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN              NaN
4     5  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN              NaN
..  ...  ...    ...      ...      ...              ...
95   96  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN              NaN
96   97  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN              NaN
97   98  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN              NaN
98   99  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN              NaN
99  100  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN              NaN

[100 rows x 6 columns]
********************************************************************************
PAGE=2
********************************************************************************
   rank nome classe item_lvl servidor mortes_temporada
0   101  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN              NaN
1   102  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN              NaN
2   103  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN              NaN
3   104  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN              NaN
4   105  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN              NaN
..  ...  ...    ...      ...      ...              ...
95  196  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN              NaN
96  197  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN              NaN
97  198  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN              NaN
98  199  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN              NaN
99  200  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN              NaN

[100 rows x 6 columns]
********************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add data to a column in Pandas, and `df` is a DataFrame, you have to include data for the rest of the columns for every row.

In your case, the fix is:

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "rank": [rank_page.text for rank_page in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[4]//div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]')],
    "nome": np.nan,
    "classe": np.nan,
    "item_lvl": np.nan,
    "servidor": np.nan,
    "mortes_temporada": np.nan
})

df = df.append(df2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!